# Having issue with Try Catch Finally script

Tags: powershell

I am working on a try/catch/finally script to do some error reporting of files that don't exist. Yes, I am working on Log4j. This is what I have so far.

```
$fileList = Get-Content "blah blah"
    foreach ($file in $fileList)
{
    try {
                Get-Item $file
                Set-ItemProperty $file -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false
                zip -d $file org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class
                Set-ItemProperty $file -Name IsReadOnly -Value $true       
        }
    catch
        {
                Write-Error "$file not found."
        }
    finally
        {
                $null = $errorreport
        }
}
$errorreport | Out-File "blah blah.csv"
```

For some reason, it puts jibberish into the output file and won't write the files into the csv that do not exist or the machine is not on. My guess is that it has something to do with the catch part but I can't figure it out.

Any help with this would be appreciated as I am a newbie when it comes to try/catch/finally things.

Thanks much!

Comment: Where in your code do you actually put something in the `$errorreport` variable? (should be in the catch)

Comment: As @Theo says I was just going to respond again. You are not building anything to put into that export. You need to make a object some place to export that.

Comment: Should Write-Error "$file not found." | Add-Content "blah blah" -Append work if I remove the $errorrerport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a pro and not sure this will help but it is easier to do this in an answer section.

```
$fileList = Get-Content "blah blah"
foreach ($file in $fileList) {
    try {
        Get-Item $file
        Set-ItemProperty $file -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false
        zip -d $file org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class
        Set-ItemProperty $file -Name IsReadOnly -Value $true
        $errorreport = [PSCustomObject]@{
            FileName = $file
        }    
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "$file not found."
    }
    finally {
        $null = $errorreport
    }
}

If ($errorreport) {
    $errorreport | Out-File "blah blah.csv"
}
Else {
    write-error "Problem"
}
```

The key part you are missing is you are not putting anything to export into `$ErrorReport`
What are your goals?
What are you trying to report?
my answer might not be great because you haven't given us enough direction.
If i was to do something like you are i would do this as follows.

```
$fileList = Get-Content "blah blah"

$Result = $fileList | ForEach-Object {
    $null = $errorreport
    try {
        Get-Item $_
        Set-ItemProperty $_ -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false
        zip -d $_ org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class
        Set-ItemProperty $_ -Name IsReadOnly -Value $true  
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "$_ not found."
        $errorreport = $true
    }

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        FileName = $_
        Error    = $errorreport
    }  
}
$Result | Out-File "blah blah.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

================Only Errors export if any. ==========below

```
$fileList = $null
$fileList = Get-Content "blah blah"

$Result = $null
$Result = $fileList | ForEach-Object {
    $null = $errorreport
    try {
        Get-Item $_
        Set-ItemProperty $_ -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false
        zip -d $_ org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class
        Set-ItemProperty $_ -Name IsReadOnly -Value $true  
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "$_ not found."
        $errorreport = $true
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            FileName = $_
            Error    = $errorreport
        } 
    } 
}

If ($Result) {
    $Result | Out-File "blah blah.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
Else {
    Write-host "No errors found"
}
```

The others above me probably did this better

Comment: I am going through a list of files that have to have the Jndilookup.class deleted from a .jar file. I need the error report to report if the file deletion was not successful. So if the machine isn't on, it dumps that to the csv file.

Comment: And your answer is great. It is clearing things up for me. Thank you very much

Comment: What part of the code is writing so much to the output file?

Comment: What I wrote above is making a two column csv export for each entry in filelist. the 2nd column if error there will be a ```$true``` otherwise ```$null```

Comment: Again the key is do you just want a report if there is an error ? mine gives you status on it all with if there is an error.

Comment: Sorry, I am just not following with the 2 columns. I only need errors machines since I have the file list already.

Comment: I added an only error output to the bottom  of my answer. But as I wrote the two folks above me tell you better ways. Mine is how I would do it. @tugger

Comment: Yours seems to work best for me to parse through and figure out. I really appreciate it. Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 2):

Tugger,

You need to add an -ErrorAction Stop switch to your Get-Item.
Here's a test program to demonstrate.

```
Try {

   Get-Item -Path "G:\Test\Junkfile.txt" 
   "No Error Detected"
}
Catch { "Error Detected!"}
Finally {"I'm done here."}
```

Sample Output:

```
Get-Item : Cannot find path 'G:\Test\Junkfile.txt' because it does not exist.
At line:3 char:4
+    Get-Item -Path "G:\Test\Junkfile.txt"
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (G:\Test\Junkfile.txt:String) [G 
   et-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetIt 
   emCommand
 
No Error Detected
I'm done here.
```

It you then add the **-ErrorAction Stop** to the Get-Item line you get:

```
Error Detected!
I'm done here.
```

Answer (score 2):

As [RetiredGeek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70624055/9898643) explains, you need to use `-ErrorAction Stop` to capture both terminating and non-terminating errors in the catch block.
You don't need the finally block and I would suggest to output an **object** inside the catch so you can write that to a proper CSV fie afterwards:

```
$fileList = Get-Content "X:\blah blah.txt"
# loop through the file paths and capture error messages in a variable
$errorreport = foreach ($file in $fileList) {
    try {
        $fileObject = Get-Item $file -ErrorAction Stop  # enters the catch block on errors
        $isReadOnly = $fileObject.IsReadOnly
        $fileObject.IsReadOnly = $false
        # I cannot check if this is correct...
        zip -d $file org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class
        $fileObject.IsReadOnly = $isReadOnly
    }
    catch {
        # in here, the $_ automatic variable represents the actual exception
        Write-Host "Error processing '$file': $($_.Exception.Message)" -ForegroundColor Red
        # output an object with the file and exception message for the CSV
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            File  = $file
            Error = $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
}

# write the error report as proper CSV file
$errorreport | Export-Csv -Path "X:\blah blah.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```